# Format XML in table row

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to format table row which contains XML data in Angular 6 application. I tried this:

```
<div class="list">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        ..............
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let processingLog of processingLogs">
        ...............
        <td>{{processingLog.title}}</td>
        <td>{{processingLog.message}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  ..........
})
export class TransactionDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  processingLogs: ProcessingLogs = new ProcessingLogs(null, null, null, null, null);
  transaction: Transaction;

  constructor(......) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.pipe(
      flatMap(params => {
        ............
      })
    ).subscribe(value => {
      if(value != null) {
        this.transaction = value;
        this.route.params.pipe(
          flatMap(params => {
            if (value.unique_id) {
              return this.processingLogsService.getProcessingLogsList(value.unique_id);
            } else {
              return of(null);
            }
          })
        ).subscribe(value => {
          if (value != null) {
            this.processingLogs = value;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Service:

```
getProcessingLogsList(processingLogsId: string): Observable<Array<ProcessingLogs>> {
    return this.http.get<Array<ProcessingLogs>>(environment.api.urls.processinglogs.getProcessinglogs(processingLogsId));
  }
```

Object:

```
export class ProcessingLogs {
  constructor(
    public title: string,
    public message: string,
  ) {}
}
```

In my case `message` contains XML data. But currently it's displayed as String. I would like to format it properly when I load it into my HTML page. Is there a way to implement it?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the HTML `<pre>` tag?

Comment: How I can apply https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-pretty-xml?

Comment: https://github.com/krtnio/angular-pretty-xml/issues/4#issuecomment-271728020

Comment: Can you show me how apply angular-pretty-xml?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I don't know what pretty-xml is supposed to do, but following the issue there, it seems as though this is how you would apply it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfhanj

Answer (score 2):

You can't use angular-pretty-xml - it was made for AngularJS, not Angular2. But you can get the code from this module and create a pipe for your project. You can see the example of such pipe here:
https://github.com/krtnio/angular-pretty-xml/issues/4#issuecomment-271728020

Answer (score 2):

We use [vkbeautify](https://github.com/vkiryukhin/vkBeautify) to display xml
So, npm install vkbeautify

then create an xml.pipe.ts file

```
import * as vkbeautify from 'vkbeautify';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
name: 'xml'
})
export class XmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(value: string): string {
    if (value)
        return vkbeautify.xml(value);
    }
}
```

You need to add this to the declarations in your appModule, and then in your html file you can have

```
<td>{{processingLog.message | xml}}</td>
```

This works for us in our Angular 7 application

Comment: Which one is better  vkbeautify or angular-pretty-xml?

Comment: All I can tell you is vkbeautify is what we ended up using in our environment, I'm not sure whether we tried angular-pretty-xml

Answer (score 1):

You could try with the xml-beautifier package.

Here is an example from the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-beautifier) :

```
import beautify from 'xml-beautifier';

const xml = beautify('<div><span>foo</span></div>');
console.log(xml); // => will output correctly indented elements
```